# Why can I run a while(true) in applicationWillTerminate?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

why can i run a while(true) in the
    applicationWillTerminate 
Method in the AppDelegate and it doesn't stop after five seconds?

I printed a log to the console and the loop is still running after a minute..

In Apples Documentation it sounds like after five seconds the Process is killed. Btw my phone was broken after this, i needed to do a hard reset.

Thanks, im just curious

Comment: Interesting.. Works on the simulator as well. The process does not get terminated.

Comment: In fact, an endless loop **anywhere** in the app will hold it from terminating. It will stay frozen at that point.

Comment: strange.  maybe that's the reason why the facebook app uses so much energy even if you killed the app ;)

Comment: btw the app disappear in the App Switcher but the process is still running.

Comment: Yes. That is the biggest issue. Terminating the App will create a kind of a zombie, where the App is still alive but cannot be reached (opened or terminated), like a dangling pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says:

> If the method does not return before time expires the system **may** kill the process altogether

The documentation says that approximately 5 seconds is the guaranteed time in which your app *won't get killed*.

I am pretty sure the app will be terminated sooner or later because iOS have background processes that make sure of it.

Infinite loops without pauses eat up CPU and its very difficult  for any operating system to recover from them.